# Get System.Web.UI.Page object (readonly) in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an MVC3 website (C#, Razor) that uses some classes written in VB.Net that do some complicated validation-stuff. Those classes need a System.Web.UI.Page object in their constructor, because they use the Request.Form and Server.MapPath from the Page-object.

I can perfectly use those old VB.Net-classes, but I need the Page-object. Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I refactor lots of code in the VB.Net classes? (Going to take hours...)

I read about why you should not use the Page-object since there are better alternatives, but I just need it to be able to use old libraries which will be refactored in a few years...

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new page object, this lets Server.MapPath() work out of the box.  Request is another story.  The easiest way I know offhand to set that is with reflection:

```
        var page = new Page();
        var requestField = typeof(Page).GetField("_request", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        requestField.SetValue(page, HttpContext.Current.Request);
```